# why is my visual basic excel code returning #value in my cell

Tags: excel, vba

why is my visual basic excel code returning #value in my cell? I am looking to extract the email address from cell A1. Below is my code

```
Function ExtractEmailAddress(s As String) As String
    Dim AtSignLocation As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim TempStr As String
    Const CharList As String = "[A-Za-Z0-9._-]"

    'Get location of the @
    AtSignLocation = InStr(s, "@")
    If AtSignLocation = 0 Then
        ExtractEmailAddress = "" 'no email address is there
    Else
        TempStr = ""
        'Get 1st half of the email address
        For i = AtSignLocation - 1 To 1 Step -1
            If Mid(s, i, 1) Like CharList Then
                    TempStr = Mid(s, i, 1) & TempStr
            Else
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i
        If TempStr = "" Then Exit Function
        'get 2nd half of the email address
        TempStr = TempStr & "@"
        For i = AtSignLocation + 1 To Len(s)
            If Mid(s, i, 1) Like CharList Then
                TempStr = TempStr & Mid(s, i, 1)
            Else
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i
    End If
    'remove trailing period if there is any
    If Right(TempStr, 1) = "." Then TempStr = _
        Left(TempStr, Len(TempStr) - 1)
    ExtractEmailAddress = TempStr
End Function
```

I have also included a screen shot of the excel VBA.

ScreenShot:

[image: ScreenShot]

Also, here is a screenshot of how its returning the value

Returned value screenshot:

[image: returned value screenshot]

Comment: In the VB editor, hit Ctrl+G to bring up the *immediate* toolwindow, then type `?ExtractEmailAddress("abc@def.xyz")` - get an error? which line?

Comment: I typed that extra line in ?ExtractEmailAddress("abc@def.com") and it returned run-time error '93': invalid pattern string

Answer (score 2):

I get "Invalid pattern string" error here:

> ```
> If Mid(s, i, 1) Like CharList Then
> ```

The problem is with the `CharList` constant:

> ```
> Const CharList As String = "[A-Za-Z0-9._-]"
> ```

Replace `A-Za-Z` with `A-Za-z` and the function starts working =)

```
Const CharList As String = "[A-Za-z0-9._-]"
```

Comment: Beat me by 2 seconds.  :)  +1

Comment: @dn18 the most important takeaway isn't the typo though, it's learning to use the *immediate* toolwindow and breakpoints (F9) to debug a UDF =)

Comment: Another follow up question. I now need to drag that formula down 950,000 rows. I know it sounds crazy, but dragging it down will take forever. Flashfill doesnt work for some reason. Any tips?